# expand and collapse an item and remove static text from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have the following java script code to expand and collapse.

```
$(function () {

   $(document).on('click', '.expandcollapse', function(e) {

     $('.collapse').each(function(index) {
       $(this).collapse("toggle");
     });

     if ($(this).html() == "<i class=\"icon-white icon-plus-sign\"></i> Expand All ") {
        $(this).html("<i class=\"icon-white icon-minus-sign\"></i> Collapse All");
     }
     else {
        $(this).html("<i class=\"icon-white icon-plus-sign\"></i> Expand All");
     } 
    });
});
```

It works fine here:

http://jsfiddle.net/HqXMN/10/

I need to remove the static text (Expand, Collapse) and somehow place them in my html.
Is there a way to hide the text and icon plus or minus sign based on the action using the toggleClass function.

Here is what I tried so far but doesnt work at all.

```
$(function () {

   $(document).on('click', '.expandcollapse', function(e) {

     $(this).removeClass('icon-white icon-minus-sign');
     $('.collapse').each(function(index) {
       $(this).collapse("toggle");
     });

     if ($(this).html() == "<i class=\"icon-white icon-plus-sign\"></i>") {
        $(this).removeClass('icon-white icon-plus-sign');
        $(this).addClass('icon-white icon-minus-sign');
        //$(this).html("<i class=\"icon-white icon-minus-sign\"></i> Collapse All");
     }
     else {
        $(this).addClass('icon-white icon-plus-sign');
        $(this).removeClass('icon-white icon-minus-sign');

     } 
    });
});
```

Here is my html (I am using haml syntax)

```
 %i.icon-white.icon-plus-sign
    Expand All
  %i.icon-white.icon-minus-sign
    Collapse All
```

Update: Here is something more I tried but couldnt make it work.
http://jsfiddle.net/HqXMN/11/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I suggest that you should use jQuery `.is()` ( http://api.jquery.com/is/ ) for your if statements, that way your code will be more flexible. Then, I suppose the `toggleClass` will work for you too. I didn't do much, but here is a start:

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.expandcollapse', function (e) {

        $('.collapse').each(function (index) {
            $(this).collapse("toggle");
        });

        if ($(this).is('.icon.white-icon .iconplus-sign')) {
            $(this).toggleClass('is-collapsed');
        } else {
            $(this).toggleClass('is-collapsed');

        }
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.expandcollapse .icon-plus-sign {
    display:block;
}
.expandcollapse .icon-minus-sign {
    display:none;
}
.is-collapsed .icon-plus-sign {
    display:none;
}
.is-collapsed .icon-minus-sign {
    display:block;
}
```

and demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/pavloschris/HqXMN/13/

I hope it helps.